# Call Lua functions from repmo-vim

Tags: repeated-commands

Repmo lets me repeat a motion, eg after typing 3j I can press ; to move another 3 lines down, or press , to move 3 lines up.

I can map a new key with its forward and backward counterparts like so:

```
nmap <expr> f repmo#Key('<Plug>(QuickScopef)', '<Plug>(QuickScopeF)')
nmap <expr> F repmo#Key('<Plug>(QuickScopeF)', '<Plug>(QuickScopef)')
```

How would I go about mapping a call to a Lua function?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the link between repmo and lua. May be if you elaborate more about your goal we will be able help you better :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
nnoremap <C-s> <cmd> lua myluafunction()<CR>
```

Comment: I think you inverted the C-s and the cmd

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble I have corrected the answer.